# What is the proper order of initialization of OpenGL inside a QT GraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

The following QT sample is straightforward : I'm trying to find out why the texture shows up only if the application gets timed by a the MessageBox. I'm using QT4.8.1 and tried it both under linux and VS2008.

```
#include "ui_qtgltest.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

class GLItem : public QGraphicsPixmapItem  // an item that issue opengl commands
{
    GLuint texture[1] ;
    GLsizei W, H;
public:

    GLItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = NULL) : QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent){
            // when the following line is commented out, the texture doesn't show up.
        QMessageBox::warning(NULL,QString("???"),QString("hold on a second") );

        QImage img( "im0.png" ) ;
        QImage GL_formatted_image;
        GL_formatted_image = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(img);
        W = GL_formatted_image.width();
        H = GL_formatted_image.height();

        glGenTextures(1, texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);           
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
            GL_formatted_image.width(), GL_formatted_image.height(),
            0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_formatted_image.bits() );


        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR ); 
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    }

    ~GLItem(void){}

    void paint(QPainter *paint, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    {
        paint->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        paint->beginNativePainting();

        glClearColor( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();
        glEnable    ( GL_BLEND ) ;
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i( 1, 0 );    glColor3f(1,0,0); glVertex2f( W,    0.0f);
        glTexCoord2i( 1, 1 );    glColor3f(0,1,0); glVertex2f( W,    H);
        glTexCoord2i( 0, 1 );    glColor3f(0,0,1); glVertex2f( 0.0f, H);
        glTexCoord2i( 0, 0 );    glColor3f(1,0,1); glVertex2f( 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();

        paint->endNativePainting();
    }
};

class QTGL: public QMainWindow
{
public: 
    QTGL(QWidget *parent =0, Qt::WFlags flags=0) : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
    {
        ui.setupUi(this);
    }

    void setup() 
    {           
        QGLWidget   * glw   = new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)); 
        QGraphicsScene  * s = new QGraphicsScene();
        QGraphicsView   * g =  ui.graphicsView;
        g->setViewport(glw); 
        g->setScene(s);

        GLItem * gi = new GLItem();
        s->addItem( gi ); 


        QTimer  * timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), s, SLOT(update()));
        timer->start(10); 
    }   

    ~QTGL() {}

private:
    Ui::mainWindow ui;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTGL w;
    w.show();
    w.setup();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Any idea on how to debug this and figure out what is going on inside ?

Comment: When the messagebox is launched, your main window with the texture loses focus, then gains it again when you close the msgbox. If you remove the display of the MessageBox, then when you run it minimize the window, then show it again, does it also render the texture?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have a similar problem here with a QGraphicsPixmapItem in Qt 4.8.0. There's a QGraphicsView using a QGLWidget as its view and it draws the QGraphicsPixmapItem and another (custom) QGraphicsItem. The QGraphicsPixmapItem is sometimes not displayed, but when I put a breakpoint somewhere and stop there before painting it always is...